# Word 2007 Interop Document.Open fails without error

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I'm trying to get Word Interop working on our build server.  Everything is great on my local machine but on the build server I get back a null document object without any exceptions.

Any idea why I wouldn't get any errors?